# Dynamically naming an image file with another field name in Django2

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to save an image file with the name changed to that of another field in the same form.

After some experimentation, it works well by using a handler function in the model, just when the object has been returned to the model for saving.  I deconstruct the file object and can assign it a name that I want, However, I am not able to deconstruct the Charfield object and dynamically pass the first field name to the image file.

```
    from django.db import models
    import os

    #handler function to customise file name.
    def photo_path(instance, filename):
        basefilename, file_extension= os.path.splitext(filename)
        return '{add}/{room}/{basename}{ext}'.format
             (add='my_Add', room="should_Be_room_type", basename= basefilename, ext= file_extension)
```

And the model is:

```
    class Room(models.Model):
        room_type = models.CharField( max_length=50)  # i.e bedroom /living room etc
        room_size = models.CharField( max_length=50)
        img = models.ImageField( upload_to=photo_path, null=True, blank=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.room_type
```

Answer (score 0):

in your case, the argument `instance` would be your Room instance, and you can use it to recover `room_type` and `room_size`. As the instance won't be created until after the image uploads, the only thing that won't be available on `photo_path` will be `instance.id`, but you don't need it.

Your function then, can be written as:

```
def photo_path(instance, filename):
        basefilename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
        return '{add}/{room}/{basename}{ext}'.format
             (add='my_Add', room=instance.room_type, basename=basefilename, ext=file_extension)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I ended up solving it in the view.py by using

```
my_room_type = request.POST['room_type']
initial_obj = form.save(commit=False)
initial_obj.save()
```

The idea was to get the value entered for the 'room_type' and print it on the image. It now works thanks.